# Trouble getting Mobile Navigation menu working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to create this mobile menu.

https://anythinggraphic.net/responsive-mobile-navigation-menu/

I have added all of the code and when I get the page into a mobile viewport, the page does nothing but show the two sets of periods "...". Unlike in the snippet, the page actually shows the list, just when it gets to the listed viewport, it shows the periods. I have the meta viewport code implemented and the Jquery vocab.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function() {
 // Insert Responsive Navigation Icon, Close Icon, and Overlay
 // If you have access to your HTML, you should put this directly into your markup.
 $('<div class="responsive-nav-icon" />').appendTo('.row.one');
 $('<div class="responsive-nav-close" />').appendTo('nav');
 $('<div id="overlay" />').insertAfter('footer');

 // Navigation Slide In
 $('.responsive-nav-icon').click(function() {
  $('nav').addClass('slide-in');
  $('html').css("overflow", "hidden");
  $('#overlay').show();
  return false;
 });

 // Navigation Slide Out
 $('#overlay, .responsive-nav-close').click(function() {
  $('nav').removeClass('slide-in');
  $('html').css("overflow", "auto");
  $('#overlay').hide();
  return false;
 });
});
});
```

```css
.responsive-nav-icon::before,
.responsive-nav-close::before {
    color: #93a748;
    content: "\f0c9";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: relative;
}

.responsive-nav-close::before {
    color: #93a748;
    content: "\f00d";
    font-size: 18px;
}

.responsive-nav-icon {
 background: #fff;
 line-height: normal;
 padding: 5px 8px 4px;
 top: 5%; left: 5%;
}

.responsive-nav-icon:hover,
.responsive-nav-close:hover {
 opacity: .7;
}

.responsive-nav-close {
 top: 10px; right: 10px;
}

.responsive-nav-icon,
.responsive-nav-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

#overlay {
    background: 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 90;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 .responsive-nav-icon,
 .responsive-nav-close {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 nav {
     height: 100%;
     padding: 20px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0; left: -400px;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
     -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
     transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
     width: 0;
 }
 
 nav.slide-in {
     left: 0;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     width: 280px;
     z-index: 100;
 }
 
 nav .menu-item {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="site-header" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" itemscope="itemscope" role="banner">
  <div class="wrap">
   <nav itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope="itemscope" role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">About</a>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#">Login</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
  
 <main class="content" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" role="main">
  ...
 </main>
  
 <footer class="site-footer" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter" itemscope="itemscope" role="contentinfo">
  ...
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not linking the responsive jquery file ... css-jquery-responsive-mobile-navigation-menu.js

Comment: i can see your html code. you've only linked the jquery file .`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` You also need to link the jquery script that runs the menu.

Comment: I had the jquery script coded into my page. I am unsure of what other link you are referring to.